# Need Dynamic Date in XML request (Shell Script)

Tags: xml, shell, date, dynamic

Need help, I have a XML request (request.xml) which I use to generate response using curl, below is the tag:

```
<StartDt>20150615</StartDt>
```

Can I make this date dynamic, so that, whenever I send my request it always take the future date (3 weeks from now)?

Below command line gives me a desired date:

```
date -d 'now + 3 weeks' +%Y%m%d
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in a way that's fully robust, install XMLStarlet and pipe your XML document through:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u //StartDt -v "$(date -d 'now + 3 weeks' +%Y%m%d)" <request.xml
```

To break that down:

```
  xmlstarlet ed -u //StartDt -v "$(date -d 'now + 3 weeks' +%Y%m%d)"
# ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# |          |  |            \- value to substitute when expression is matched
# |          |  \- XPath expression to match content to edit
# |          \- edit subcommand
# \- generic tool for editing, selecting from, &c. XML.
```

`//StartDt` is XPath to match all elements named `StartDt`, wherever they are in the document. XPath is a quite expressive language (though libxml, the library serving the backend here, only supports the 1.0 version) -- so you can quite straightforwardly filter further.

Comment: Nice tool! My best approach would have been `xsltproc`, but this would be much more verbose compared to `xmlstarlet`.